# Desire specific size of Visual Studio 2019 Extension ToolWindow ( WPF UserControl )

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019, vsix

I am looking to get a fix size windows because of content that I am showing.  I am struggling because when the extension is run the size of windows is crop to a fix size.  The simple example is just modified the default and try to make it 800x600 window. Once the window is up on screen, you can manual adjust and next time it will be fine but I wish to make sure the default is correct.

I seen other questions about like not having fix size and such and nothing seems to work.  I understand if user changes the size smaller than it will be that may - but I would like default size to be bigger

```
<UserControl x:Class="VSIXProject1.ToolWindow1Control"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:vsshell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0"
         Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowKey}}"
         Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowTextKey}}"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800"
         Name="MyToolWindow">
<Grid MinWidth="800" MinHeight="600">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="800" Height="600">
        <TextBlock Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center">ToolWindow1</TextBlock>
        <Button Content="Click me!" Click="button1_Click" Width="120" Height="80" Name="button1"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRIBK.jpg)
[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUVNG.png)

I try following code in Package class as recommended

```
 [ProvideToolWindow(typeof(ToolWindow1),
                       Width =800,
                       Height =600,
                       Style = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsDockStyle.AlwaysFloat)]
```

Comment: I have place the code for the test in the following repo

https://github.com/HStewartGitHome/VSIXToolWindowIssue

Comment: How about use [ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.resizemode?view=netcore-3.1) to make the window could resize with a button?

Comment: I not sure this will help.   This control works fine in normal WPF application but not in Visual Studio 2019 Extension.  What I desiring is the develop does not have to resize the dialog on first execution.  Of course you can always resize it and it sticks but it just looks bad on my extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can stipulate the initial size of a toolwindow by setting the Width and Height properties, via the [ProvideToolWindowAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.providetoolwindowattribute.style?view=visualstudiosdk-2019), used to register your toolwindow. Toolwindows are "sticky", with the position, size, dockstate etc being persisted with your other window layout options. Meaning, once the user resizes/docs/floats the toolwindow, it's state gets saved. But you can readily reset it back to the default, using the Windows | Reset Window Layout menu command.

Sincerely,

Comment: Thanks this looks very hopeful and I will try it and respond back.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work,  it based off the Microsoft doc.  Do you know of example code that that 
implemented a larger toolwindow in  Visual Studio 2019 - this extension required 2019.

       [ProvideToolWindow(typeof(ToolWindow1),
                       Width =800,
                       Height =600,
                       Style = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsDockStyle.AlwaysFloat)]

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can set the Window size in this way

```
<UserControl x:Class="VSIXProject1.ToolWindow1Control"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:vsshell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0"
     Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowKey}}"
     Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowTextKey}}"
     MinWidth = "800"
     MinHeight = "600"
     mc:Ignorable="d"
     d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800"
     Name="MyToolWindow">
```

Set the `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` will ensure that window will never go under that dimension

Comment: This is not that simple,  I try this and  had the size adjusted - you got to make sure that either new project or reset the position and size so it small like the default.  Also this is Visual Studio 2019.  I need someone to try it

Comment: So the user can resize it but at next show/start should be again the same you defined in the xaml?

Comment: This is an extension,  so the application is Visual Studio 2019.  But user can resize it to be correct but it comes up incorrect on first time.